# Scala Spark - illegal start of definition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

This is probably a stupid newbie mistake, but I'm getting an error running what I thought was basic Scala code (in a Spark notebook, via Jupyter notebook):

```
val sampleDF = spark.read.parquet("/data/my_data.parquet")

sampleDF
  .limit(5)
  .write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://sql.example.com;database=my_database")
  .option("dbtable", "my_schema.test_table")
  .option("user", "foo")
  .option("password", "bar")
  .save()
```

The error:

```
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
    .limit(5)
    ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't know anything about jupyter internals, but I suspect that it's an artifact from the jupyter-repl interaction. `sampleDF` is for some reason considered to be a complete statement on its own. Try

```
(sampleDF
  .limit(5)
  .write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://sql.example.com;database=my_database")
  .option("dbtable", "my_schema.test_table")
  .option("user", "foo")
  .option("password", "bar")
  .save())
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. I feel like this is something they should have fixed a long time ago...

Comment: @shadowtalker Maybe report it as a jupyter bug, I don't know...? However, my estimation is: if it's built on top of the ordinary scala repl, this could be surprisingly hard to fix. Semicolon inference & interactive repls can be somewhat tricky...

Comment: Savior of life.

Answer (score 6):

Jupyter would try to interpret each line as a complete command, so `sampleDF` is first interpreted as a valid expression, and then it moves to the next line, producing an error. Move the dots to the previous line, to let the interpreter know that "there's more stuff coming":

```
sampleDF.
  limit(5).
  write.
  format("jdbc").
  option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://sql.example.com;database=my_database").
  option("dbtable", "my_schema.test_table").
  option("user", "foo").
  option("password", "bar").
  save()
```

Comment: Ugh. This is what I am now using. Notable that Zeppelin notebooks don't have this problem, and you can split long commands in the usual way.